# elvis operators in kotlin.. foo.bar?.let(return true)?:return false

Tags: kotlin

what does the following code do? would I get the same result if I replaced `let` with `run` or `apply` ?

```
foo.bar?.let(return true)?:return false
```

is this equivalent to

```
return foo.getbar() != null
```

in java ?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting code. Yes it does what you expect. The `let` is executed if `bar` is not pointing to `null`, otherwise the Elvis operation comes into play and `false` is being returned.

Should be refactored to `return foo.bar != null`.

I guess `let` is called with a lambda in `“{}”` actually?